# Redei and Camion-Moon Theorems- proving by contradiction

Tags: graph-theory, solution-verification, proof-writing, proof-explanation

[Redei theorem](http://ravi-bhide.blogspot.com/2012/11/redeis-theorem.html#:%7E:text=Conclusion,on%2C%20which%20beat%20team%20N.) is about [Hamiltonian paths](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_path) whiles [Camion-Moon theorem](https://books.google.com/books?id=IHJgDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA38&lpg=PA38&dq=camion-moon%20theorem%20proof&source=bl&ots=--z5KUfqmG&sig=ACfU3U254t7En8ZGgQng353TBpBN8cjl7g&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjb2rOy5633AhXvQjABHWJpCm4Q6AF6BAgTEAM#v=onepage&q=camion-moon%20theorem%20proof&f=false) is about [Hamiltonian cycles](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/HamiltonianCycle.html). These two theorems are well known with variant proves to them (mostly by induction).

I feel induction is lengthy and proving by contradiction is somehow shorter. I need a critical proofread to detect any anomalies and possible suggestion to my proves:

*Redei theorem states that every tournament has a directed Hamiltonan path. Camion-Moon theorem also states that every strongly connected tournament has a directed Hamiltonian cycle.*

Contradictory poof of Radei theorem: Assume the path $P=v_1v_2, \ldots v_k$ is the longest directed path in the tournament $T$. Clearly, if $P$ contains all these vertices then there exist a Hamiltonian path in $T$. If not, then there exist a certain vertex $x$ that is not on the path of $P.$ Since $P$ cannot be extended beyond its original length then, there must be an edge directions $v_1 \rightarrow x$ and $x \rightarrow v_k$. There is an index $i$ such that the directions are changing $v_i\rightarrow x$ and $x\rightarrow v_{i+1}$. We now have a new path $v_1 \ldots v_i x v_{i+1} \ldots v_k$ which is longer than before. This is a contradiction. Thus, we conclude that every tournament $T$ has a directed Hamiltonian path.

Contradictory poof of Camion-Moon theorem: similar to the above prove, we let $C_1 =v_1v_2, v_2v_3, \ldots, v_{n-1}v_n, v_nv_1$ be the the path of the longest cycle of a strongly connected tournament $T$ such that there is a certain vertex $x$ which is not covered by $C_1$. Since $T$ is strongly connected, there is an index $i$ such that the directions of the paths in $C_1$ can connects with $x$ so that we can construct a larger cycle $C_2 =v_1v_2, v_2v_3 \ldots v_i x, x v_{i+1} \ldots v_{n-1}v_n, v_nv_1$ giving a contradiction that $C_1$ is the longest cycle. Similar argument exist if there is more than one vertex say $x,y$ which are not covered by $C_1$ and we can always construct a larger cycle bigger than $C_1.$ Thus, we conclude that every strogly connected tournament has Hamiltonian cycle.

Comment: That's... basically the argument by induction? (Leaving out the "Similar argument exist" bit in the second proof - you shouldn't skip the second case, even if it does make your proof shorter.)

Comment: You mean I should've fully shown the case of two vertices $x,y$? Would that be enough to make the proof complete?

Comment: Two or more vertices - you should be fully general. Also, the base case of the induction proof still needs to exist in some form here: to be able to begin by taking the longest cycle, you should show that there is a cycle.

Comment: That makes sense. But I thought $C_1$ suffices the base case? By the way is the Redei proof ok?

Comment: You define $C_1$ to be the longest cycle. This makes no sense in a transitive tournament, which has no cycles. The transitive tournament isn't strongly connected, but you never use this fact. (This is theoretically also an issue with the Redei proof, but there's no question about whether paths exist; I think the Redei proof is fine as written.)

Comment: @bof I a have included the theorem for easy reference.